# CartoDB not showing data layer over every tile

Tags: carto

https://interwebjill.cartodb.com/viz/191381e0-1a43-11e5-a909-0e43f3deba5a/map

I have columns for the latitude and longitude values of each point in my table but not all of them are being shown in the map.

Does anyone know of any workarounds? I would love to use CartoDB to analyze my preliminary data.

Answer (score 1):

We investigated this issue through the CartoDB support channel and the issue is being caused because your longitude column contains coordinates out of bounds (+-180).

In order to sort this out, you can mathematically get the complementary coordinates by using:

```
UPDATE tablename SET new_lon = (-180+(lon-180)) WHERE lon > 180
```

Where `new_lon` is a new created column to store your lon values, that go up to 220º right now and should be bounded by +-180.